# How can I use linebreak inside \coordinate, in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

well I need to write some text right next to my shape. But it's too complicated when making it all coordinate i and write it. How I make it easier?

Comment: Can you include your code into the question? Also I think you mean a node instead of a coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean `\node` since `\coordinate`s only got a name and no text …

An node with automatic line breaking needs a `text width`, e.g.

```
\node at (2,5) [text width=3cm] {Your text with breaks inside};
```

A node with manual line breaks must know how to align the text by using the `align` option, then you can define breaks with `\\`, e.g.

```
\node at (3,4) [align=right] {Your text with\\breaks inside}
```

You can further use the `positioning` library to place `node`s, like in

```
\coodinate (A) at (5,5);
\node [above right=of A] {My Node};
```

Comment: \node[anchor=north west, text width=5cm](note1) at (0,0) well but I used something like this, but thanks for your assistance!